# How to launch IGV from the terminal window

Tags: linux, terminal

I have succesfully installed the IGV program using the terminal, but for some time have not been able to start it no matter what i try. What are the necessary commands to achieve this?
`sudo apt install IGV` has worked and command output has run smoothly.

So far i have installed it multiple times, trying to figure out what is the problem, however i haven't gotten anywhere.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note:** I recommend that you remove the previously installed IGV package before performing the following steps to avoid conflicts. Simply execute:

```shell
$ sudo apt remove --purge igv
```

---

First you need at least [Java 11](http://openjdk.java.net) installed (because of incompatibility with previous versions).

Installing the Default JRE/JDK

The easiest option for installing Java is to use the version packaged with Ubuntu. By default, Ubuntu 18.04 includes Open JDK, which is an open-source variant of the JRE and JDK.

To install this version, first update the package index and upgrade your system:

```shell
$ sudo apt update && apt upgrade
```

Next, check if Java is already installed:

```shell
$ java -version
```

If Java is **not** currently installed, you'll see an output similar to this:

```shell
bash: java: Command not found.
```

Execute the following command to install OpenJDK:

```shell
$ sudo apt install default-jre
```

This command will install the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). You'll then be able to run almost all Java software.

Now verify the installation with:

```shell
$ java -version
```

You'll see the following output (the versions may differ):

```shell
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+1-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+1-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode)
```

---

The next step is to [download IGV](https://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/download) and unzip the file to a location of your choice (for example to `/opt`).

Then open that directory in a terminal (via **"Open in Terminal"**) or launch a terminal and switch to the directory via `cd` command (the name of the directory may differ):

```shell
$ cd /opt/IGV_Linux_2.5.0
```

To start IGV (from the command line), execute the following:

```shell
$ java --module-path=lib -Xmx4g @igv.args --module=org.igv/org.broad.igv.ui.Main
```

Alternatively, you can start IGV with the script `igv.sh` inside the `IGV_Linux_2.5.0` directory. You might have to make the script executable first by typing:

```shell
$ sudo chmod a+x igv.sh
```

**Note:** The command line has become a bit more complex with Java 11 compared to previous versions.

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying to my question. I tried the first command and i got the message that the default package couldn't be found

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3, the linux version is Linux 4.15.0-39-generic x86_64. I have openjdk 10.0.2 as java version, if im not misunderstanding. I ask for futher help with regard to installing version 11.0.2, please. As i wasn't able to, if i may, could you tell me those commands ? I haven't used linux for too long, have been too busy with R on windows(i have dual boot)

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a detailed step-by-step description. Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: I followed your commands for installing java and ``java -version`` still gives me the open jdk version"10.0.2" 2018-7-17 output. The system versions i told you before include bionic beaver, right? Just now, i managed to install java 11 by using these instructions:https://www.linode.com/docs/development/java/install-java-on-ubuntu-18-04/  . I now have "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS. And now, thanks to you i am able to sart IGV from the terminal. You were most helpfull, thank you. If i can ask one more thing, the commands for starting Rstudio or fastQC re similar to these that you've shown me?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! Unfortunately I'm not familiar with RStudio and fastQC and can't help you with this.

Comment: It's ok, appreciate your help.